# jQuery/CSS: darken/mask all divs/browser window - apart from one selected div

Tags: jquery, css, mask

I have some jQuery Isotope plugin logic on a one-page website in progress.

When an *item* gets *selected* and is *maximised* to show some content, I would like to **darken/dim/mask all others** after they are *minimised* - except that one that was clicked on. This is the working logic I have right now; a clicked-on *item* gets the class *selected* added, an already *selected* *item* gets the class *selected* removed when clicked on:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).children('.maximised').hide()
        $(this).children('.minimised').show()
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).children('.minimised').hide()
        $(this).children('.maximised').show()
    }
    $container.isotope('shuffle');
    $container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

Manipulating the transparency does not look good, because the background images/videos become visible. Maybe I can easily somehow "dim" the entire browser window? Ideally, I'd avoid another plugin. Do you have a suggestion how I can achieve the desired effect?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 8):

I think you're after a solution such as the following.

```
$(".item").click(function(e) {
    //code
    $("body").append($("<div>").css({
        position: "fixed"
        ,width: "100%"
        ,height: "100%"
        ,"background-color": "#000"
        ,opacity: 0.6
        ,"z-index": 999
        ,top: 0
        ,left: 0
    }).attr("id","page-cover"));
    //more code
});
```

You may of course need to play around with the `z-index` for this div, and could put all the CSS in your stylesheet.

**Alternate**

You could put this div at the end of the `BODY` tag and use this CSS:

```
#page-cover {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

With this JS:

```
//on click of .item
$("#page-cover").show().css("opacity",0.6);
```

Comment: Thanks. The latter does not work, however high the z-index. With the first version, I can see in the console that it does get appended to the body; however it does not show up.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `top` and `left` values. See amended answer.

Comment: Cheers, yes, the positioning... Now I just have to figure out, how to make the overlay disappear when the item is deselected and another item is selected. I can insert $("#page-cover").hide(); in the right place in Isotope's logic - but the overlay does of course not allow me to _click through it_ to close the item. It looks like I have to figure out how to _lift_ the selected item above the overlay so it can receive clicks, right?

Comment: Yea, assuming the selected item is absolute, or even relative you should be able to give it a `z-index` higher than the overlay, and it will appear above it.